# Video url show empty using tiktok-package in node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am using this [package](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper) to scrape the data from TikTok in node js.

**Problem**

```
console.log(body) show encoded code
```

**Code**

```
const TikTokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');
const rp = require('request');

const videoMeta = await getVideoMeta('https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok/video/6889096755028233478');

    var opt = { 
       uri: videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl,
       headers: videoMeta.headers
    };

    rp.get(opt, (error, response, body) => {

     //according to documentation, In the body it will give the video URL,
     //but it shows some encoded code

        console.log(body);
    });
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: expected result from rp.get request is videoUrl

Comment: So is `videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl` empty? Or what is its value?

Comment: It will give you the URL. Send the request on this URL (videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl ) and add some headers to access the mp4 link of the video. You can see it in my code. For more detail you can read this [package](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper) documentation section Download Video

Comment: Right, what is not clear to me is: if you are getting an URL with an mp4, the body will be an encoded video. So it looks to me that your code is working

Comment: As mention in the [issue](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper/issues/356) section, the owner of this library said you will receive the video link but I got some encoded data instead of a link. Is any wrong in my process to get the video url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite working but you need some tweak on the headers setting and in to save the file.

Here a working example:

```js
const TikTokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');
const got = require('got');
const fs = require('fs')

async function run() {

  const headers = {
    "User-Agent": "BOB",
    "Referer": "https://www.tiktok.com/",
    "Cookie": "tt_webid_v2=BOB"
  }

  const videoMeta = await TikTokScraper.getVideoMeta('https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok/video/6889096755028233478', headers);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(videoMeta, null, 2))

  const url = videoMeta.collector[0].videoUrl

  got
    .stream(url, { headers: videoMeta.headers })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.mp4'));
}

run()
```

(I used `got` because `request` is deprecated by the maintainer)

Note that there are two HTTP requests:

1. calling `TikTokScraper.getVideoMeta` to get the VIDEO URL
2. calling `rp.get` (as your scripts) using the VIDEO URL

The 2nd call will receive a video stream so it is right that it is not human readable.
But streaming that response directly to a file -since it is a byte stream-, you will be able to open it.

Comment: Hope it works. Currently, I could get any data from this package. I think my IP blocked for a lot of requests sent. Need to add some proxy for testing

Comment: I would suggest using tethering to try it. I don't know if TikTok applies some IP blocks over DDOS.

Comment: Proxy works for me. Is it possible to get the mp4 link of the video instead to download it

Comment: Yes, to avoid the download you should comment the `got.stream(..).pipe(..)` sentence

Comment: I don't think it will give any URL, because when we open the videoUrl it required some kind of headers

Comment: Maybe I don't get the point: the mp4 link to the video is contained in the `url` variable. Then this URL can be streamed adding headers, but that is the link indeed